# How to create a single word from macro arguments in Common Lisp?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I have:

```
(defmacro test (a b c)
    `'(,a ,b ,c))
```

Running `(test apple banana cuba)` gives `(APPLE BANANA CUBA)` as expected.

**How do I make the macro produce APPLEBANANACUBA?**

I tried:

```
(defmacro test (a b c)
        `'(,a,b,c))
```

but running `(test ant bites chris)` still returns `(ANT BITES CHRIS)` as a list of three separate args.

I tried variations and none seem to work. Like this one:

```
(defmacro test (a b c)
    `(apply #'concatenate 'symbol '(,a ,b ,c)))
```

Obviously, this errors out, because 'symbol isn't a valid output type for concatenate.

I am sure this is some basic misunderstanding on my part about how macros work, and there is an easy way to do this. What am I missing?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Even though the other question includes information that is the answer to this question, it is embedded in a lot of other information in both the question and answer. You can put a link in a comment to that question saying there's 'more' information there, but calling the two questions the 'same' ( which is what duplicate means) is a disservice to anyone else who might benefit from a quick clear solution in the future. Upto you really, but please do reconsider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenate them into a string, then create a symbol from that string.

```
(defmacro test (a b c)
  (intern (concatenate 'string a b c)))
```

`INTERN` will intern the string in the current package, you could also use `MAKE-SYMBOL` to create an uninterned symbol.

Answer (score 5):

**Confusion about macros and their implementation**

> I am sure this is some basic misunderstanding on my part about how macros work

Yes:

- Macros and creating 'words' are fully independent, orthogonal concepts.
- The concept of 'word' does not exist in Lisp. But there are symbols, strings, numbers, ...
- If you think of `APPLEBANANACUBA` then you probably mean a *symbol*.

**Solving the problem**

1. first solve the problem how to create a symbol from a list of symbols
2. implement the macro

If you want to create a new symbol which is the concatenation of symbols, then you need to:

1. get the symbols, take their names as strings
2. create a string which is the concatenation of these names
3. create a symbol from that string, possibly in a package.

**Implode operation**

Let's call this operation *implode*, which is the historical name for it:

```
(defun implode-symbols (symbols &optional (package *package*))
  (when symbols
    (values
     (intern (with-output-to-string (stream)
               (dolist (symbol symbols)
                 (write-string (symbol-name symbol) stream)))
             package))))


CL-USER 30 > (implode-symbols '(a - b - c - foo - bar))
A-B-C-FOO-BAR
```

Now, one can make a more general version, which can *implode* all things:

```
(defun implode (things)
  (when things
    (values
     (intern (with-output-to-string (stream)
               (dolist (thing things)
                 (princ thing stream)))))))

CL-USER 31 > (implode '(a - b - c - foo :bar - 42 - "BAZ"))
A-B-C-FOOBAR-42-BAZ
```

**A macro imploding some arguments**

Given that we a function which creates a symbol from a list of things, we can easily write the macro:

```
CL-USER 37 > (defmacro test (a b c)
               `',(implode (list a b c)))
TEST

CL-USER 38 > (macroexpand-1 '(test foo bar baz))
(QUOTE FOOBARBAZ)
T

CL-USER 39 > (test foo bar baz)
FOOBARBAZ
```

**Atoms, imploding and exploding**

Symbols are atoms. Which means they are not cons cells, which are a basic building block of linked lists.

You can explode and implode an atom, here a symbol.

- implode the symbols `FOO` and `BAR` -> `FOOBAR`
- explode the symbol `FOOBAR` -> `F`, `O`, `O`, `B`, `A`, `R`

Comment: That's a great clarification. Thanks. What then is the text that is passed to a macro? That is, I can call (test foo bar baz) without having to quote the args as 'foo 'bar 'baz. However if test were a function and not a macro, (test foo bar baz) will look for variables foo bar baz. What is the thing that is passéd to a macro? An atom? A symbol? Or something else? It seems like it's just text...

Comment: @λ-: why not try it out? Ask the macro what the values of A, B, and C are. DESCRIBE is your friend. Lisp macros have nothing to do with *text*. It's all data.